# Web part removes itself with an error

Tags: error, custom-list, content-editor-web-part

I have a custom list and I'm trying to add a web part. After I add the web part I click "Modify Shared Web Part". The web part dissapears and I get the following error

[image: web part error]

I am definitely the only one editing this page and this happens every time I have tried to add one. If I come out of edit page then my original list is not showing and I have to re-navigate to the list/view I was trying to edit

Answer (score 0):

my advice is check the page with ?contents=1.
eventually close and delete all unused webparts, or just remove them all and leave just the view and start over